# Complete HOCON configuration for Akka.Net

Tags: scala, akka.net, akka.net-cluster

I am looking for all the available parameters and their allowed values with meaning which I can configure in HOCON configuration with Akk.Net. I have got some links but they do not have the list of all the available paraments or they aren't available:

http://getakka.net/articles/concepts/configuration.html

```
https://github.com/petabridge/akka-bootcamp/tree/master/src/Unit-2/lesson1
http://getakka.net/docs/concepts/configuration
```

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/general/configuration.html. 
It provides some more info but I am more interested in any Akka.Net specific details.

Answer (score 4):

The reference configuration file is `/src/core/Akka/Configuration/Pigeon.conf` in the GitHub repository. For example, for the 1.3 branch: https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/v1.3.0/src/core/Akka/Configuration/Pigeon.conf

Comment: Thanks chunjef for the answer. I did not know about the purpose of Pigeon.conf file. Thanks for saving a life mate.